# How can django debug toolbar be set to work for just some users?

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

Right away: yes I know about INTERNAL_IPS.

I'm about to have my django app opened up at work integration and testing. I know there will be debugging and plenty modifications and/or optimizations to be made so I'd love to have the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). However, I'd prefer to not have it up for all of my co-workers (who are the 'clients').

The reason the INTERNAL_IP setting doens't work for just me (btw: I have a static IP on my development computer) is that I am using [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/) as a reverse-proxy and serving with [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). Because of the reverse-proxy, using an internal_ip of 127.0.0.1 shows DjDT to any computer on the network and using that ip is the only way I've been able to see it myself.

**What I'm looking for is either a way to get my IP or my login name to be the only one to access the toolbar.** I once saw a thread about the user name limited access but I can't find it...

And as a side question- anyone know why the toolbar doesn't render in IE? For me it just shows as tables on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try:

```
def show_toolbar(request):
    return not request.is_ajax() and request.user and request.user.username == "yourusername"

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'projectname.settings.show_toolbar',
    # Rest of config
}
```

Comment: this works just fine, with the one change that it should be `request.user.username`. I got pretty hung-up on trying to find a way to add it via IP that I didn't really think about something like this and also didn't know about the callback setting. thanks

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is no longer correct. Newer versions of the toolbar need the value of the `SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK` key to be a string with the full import path of the function. So if you're defining your callback function your `settings.py` file, you'd have to add:

```
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'projectname.settings.show_toolbar',
}
```

Comment: That's what the `edit` function is for. I took the liberty and incorporated your comment into the accepted answer.

Comment: @jnns oh, I hadn't realized I could propose an edit to another answer. Gr8!

Answer (score 2):

If you face `No .rsplit() Error`. NEW SOLUTION:

Because `SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK` is now a dotted string path and not support a callable.

edit your `settings.py`:

```
def custom_show_toolbar(request):
     return True  # Always show toolbar, for example purposes only.

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'your_project_name.settings.custom_show_toolbar',
}
```

Comment: the accepted answer was edited to account for this change a while ago.

Comment: @j_syk, sorry for my mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 4+ this username validation worked for me:

```
def show_toolbar(request):
    return str(request.user) == "username" #... any other validations
```