# Show django-debug-toolbar to specific users

Tags: python, django, debugging

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548947/how-can-django-debug-toolbar-be-set-to-work-for-just-some-users/6549317#6549317) over the issue of DjDT. However when I implement it gives an error.

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

This is my code

```
def show_toolbar(request):
return not request.is_ajax() and request.user and request.user.username == 'ptar'


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': 'libert.settings.show_toolbar',}
```

MIDDLEWARES

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
"debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",#
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'session_security.middleware.SessionSecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'online_users.middleware.OnlineNowMiddleware',
#'user_visit.middleware.UserVisitMiddleware',
#'django_htmx.middleware.HtmxMiddleware',
```

]

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your `MIDDLEWARE` settings?

Comment: @Flimm. Middleware settings added

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by putting the `debugtoolbarMiddleware` after the `AuthenticationMiddleware`
Thank you @Flimm for taking me towards that direction.